# Log4J - One log file per thread in an environment with dynamic thread creation

Tags: java, log4j

Let me begin with a brief explanation of the system I am using:

We have a system that runs as a Daemon, running work-units as they come in. This daemon dynamically creates a new Thread when it is given a new work-unit. For each of these units of work, I need Log4J to create a new log file to append to - the filename will be provided at runtime, when the new log file must be created. This daemon must be able to remain alive indefinitely, which I believe causes some memory concerns, as I will explain.

My first thought was to create a new Logger for each work-unit, naming it after the thread, of course. The work-unit's thread retains a reference to that Logger. When the unit is finished, it will be garbage-collected, but the problem is that Log4J itself retains a reference to the Logger, which will never be used again. It seems likely that all these Loggers will cause the VM to run out of memory.

Another solution: subclass Filter, to filter Appenders by the thread names, and place them on the same Logger. Then, remove the Appenders as the work-units complete. Of course, this necessitates adding the code to remove the appenders. That will be a lot of code changes.

I've looked into NDC and MDC, which appear to be intended for managing interleaved output to the same file. I've considered proposing this as a solution, but I don't think it will be accepted.

I want to say that Log4J appears that it is intended *not* to function this way, that is, dynamically creating new log files at runtime, as they are required (or desired). So I am not sure which direction to look in next - Is log4j not the solution here, or did I comPLETELY miss something? Have I not looked closely enough at NDC? Or is my concern with Log4J holding onto Loggers a nonissue for reasons I don't see?

Comment: Instead of using as logger to indirectly create a new file each time, you could write to a new file with FileWriter and close it when you have finished with it.

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a new log method that wraps the normal log method, and append thread id.
Something like the following (oversimplified, but you get the idea).  Log4j is already thread save I believe, so as long as you aren't logging a ton, you should be fine.  Then you can easily grep on thread id.

```
public log(long id, String message)
{
   logger.log("ThreadId: id + "message: " + message);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

That would log the output for all the threads to the same file, correct? That isn't the solution I am looking for. I'm not looking to ensure thread safety; I know Log4J does that.

Comment: Check the links supplied in this question. Looks like they were trying to do the same, but with requests rather than threads. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331128/log4j-one-log-file-per-request?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

ThreadLocal appears to be the solution for you.