# How to create log file based on session id and logged in user name and How to create one log file per session? in java mvc

Tags: java

I am using `log4j` to get all logger information and in log4j.xml, I given web.log and logs are getting printed in this file.

But I want to create a different log file based on session id and logged in username for every user logged in.

Please let me know how can I do this job?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1239227/1531971

Comment: You will need to add appenders in code and then use them to log to the proper logfile. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9003191/10455672 which describes the exact same problem.

Comment: thanks for replay @GerbenJongerius please provide any example i can understand how it exactly works